# Best place to check headers for a CSV file in with kiba ETL

Tags: kiba-etl

I need to check that :

- header line is present
- header contain a specfic set of headers

What the best place to do that. I have some possible solution but don't know the more idiomatic one

- Check before running the full ETL for exemple before the `Kiba.parse` block
- Check in a `pre_process` block inside the ETL
- check in the ETL source. I tend to prefer this one since it will be more reusable (need to pass the mandatory field as params)

Note that even if I can check in a `transform` block what field are available on the `row`, this solution seem not very efficient since it will run for each line.

Any hints appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various & all quite idiomatic ways to achieve this:

### At the source level (passing an array of headers)

You can use `CSV` without `headers: true`, which offers the opportunity to finely check the headers:

```rb
class CSVSource
  def initialize(filename:, csv_options:, expected_headers:)
  # SNIP

  def each
    CSV.foreach(filename, csv_options).with_index do |row, file_row_index|
      if file_row_index == 0
        check_headers!(actual: row.to_a, expected: expected_headers)
        next # do not propagate the headers row
      else
        yield(Hash[expected_headers.zip(row.to_a)])
      end
    end
  end

  def check_headers!(actual:, expected:)
  # SNIP - verify uniqueness, presence, raise a clear message if needed
end
```

### At the source level (letting the caller define the behaviour using a lambda)

```rb
class CSVSource
  def initialize(after_headers_read_callback:, ...)
    @after_headers_read_callback = ...

  def each
    CSV.foreach(filename, csv_options).with_index do |row, file_row_index|
      if file_row_index == 0
        @after_headers_read_callback.call(row.to_a)
        next
      end
      # ...
    end
  end
```

The lambda will let the caller define their own checks, raise if needed etc, which is better for reuse.

### At the transform level

If you want to further decouple the components (e.g. separate the headers handling from the fact that rows come from a CSV source), you can use a transform.

I commonly use this design, which allows for better reuse (here with a CSV source which will yield a bit of meta-data):

```rb
def transform_array_rows_to_hash_rows(after_headers_read_callback:)
  transform do |row|
    if row.fetch(:file_row_index) == 0
      @headers = row.fetch(:row)
      after_headers_read_callback.call(@headers)
      nil
    else
      Hash[@headers.zip(row.fetch(:row))].merge(
        filename: row.fetch(:filename),
        file_row_index: row.fetch(:file_row_index)
      )
    end
  end
end
```

### What's not recommended

In all cases, avoid doing any processing in `Kiba.parse` itself. It's a better design to ensure IO will only occur when you are calling `Kiba.run` (since it will be more future-proof and will support introspection features in later versions of Kiba).

Also, using `pre_process` isn't recommended (while it will work), because it will lead to a bit of duplication etc.

Hope this helps, and let me know if this isn't clear!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Will go down the lambda road on this one. Little bit off but cool idea to have a method that add the `transform` blok like in your `transform_array_rows_to_hash_rows` exemple

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this way to do things works well for "meta transforms" of sorts. I will share more example of use in the future, because it's quite powerful!